# file not found exception even i have

Tags: exception, netbeans

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: other\pappm101.ini (The system cannot find the path specified)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method)
```

I have the folder and the file, even then I'm getting the same exception again and again.

I am compiling this file by netbeans.

Comment: Show complete code or some relevant idea ! Can't get your question ?

Comment: Probably the folder “other” does not exist where you think that Java thinks it should be. Check what path you are executing your code from.

Comment: Is this running on Unix or DOS/Windows?

Comment: for debugging purposes doing System.out.println("System.getProperty("user.dir")) will show you were the root is for relative file access.

Comment: -1 because I can't figure out what you want us to tell you: the definition of `FileNotFoundException`, how to make the exception go away or some other thing entirely

Answer (score 1):

The application's working directory is not what you think it is.  However you're running the application, check that its working directory is set to the directory above your `other` directory.

Comment: thanks.............. now it works...........i have just added through the option add jar/folder in net beans......

Comment: Mohsin, the normal thing in this situation is to mark the answer as correct - the check mark that you see on the left.

Answer (score 0):

What about the driver and the aprent folder name? the name: `other\pappm101.ini` is a relative path and not absolute. Tt looks like your application doesnt search where you think it does!